# @yield not Displaying on Screen

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, yield

I just started learning Laravel framework in order to start a new project. However, I have encountered a problem where the @yield function does not display the section on the screen. However, if I put a letter in front of @yield in creates a text "x@yield('section')" which means that the @yield('section') does not do anything. Please, explain why does this happen.

aims\routes\web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

aims\resources\views\content.blade.php

```
@extends('welcome')
@section('contents')

    <div>
        <h1>HELLO</h1>
    </div>

    
@endsection
```

aims\resources\views\welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
        <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<body class="antialiased">
@yield('contents')
    </body>
</html>
```

Explanations why this particular error occured and the solution to fix it.

Comment: update your route to this

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('content');
    });

Answer (score 2):

You should call the content, Not the extended.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('content'); // <-- Change this
});
```

---

Example

**In main page(blade)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>@yield('title', 'Default Title')</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <footer>
        @yield('footer', 'Default Footer Content')
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**In Inner pages**

```
@extends('master') # This will get the above page data

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('content')
    <h1>Welcome to the page!</h1>
    <p>This is the main content for this page.</p>
@endsection

@section('footer')
    <p>Specific footer for this page.</p>
@endsection
```

> When you call the inner page(second code), automatically, all data on the main blade will render proper HTML at the end.